# Permission denied /opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/learning_nxt

Tags: ros, nxt, permission, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid and ROS Electric. I had successfully installed the NXT packages for ROS and tested them with my brick. Everything seemed to be going well. I'm trying to do the [NXT tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_ros/Tutorials/Getting%20started):

Entered: `roscd nxt`

Brought me to: `/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt`

Entered: `roscreate-pkg learning_nxt rospy nxt_ros`

Returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 35, in <module>
    roscreate.roscreatepkg.roscreatepkg_main()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 125, in roscreatepkg_main
    create_package(package, author_name(), depends, uses_roscpp=uses_roscpp, uses_rospy=uses_rospy)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 63, in create_package
    os.makedirs(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/learning_nxt'
```

Before this I had been using roscreate-pkg just fine with the regular ROS tutorials. Now that I'm trying to use it with the NXT packages, it seems to not work.

EDIT 1: In reply to Lorenz, thank you. That is one thing that has confused me about the differences between Fuerte and Electric. In the installing Electric tutorial page, overlays aren't mentioned and I feel like my bashrc isn't setup the way it should be, even though I followed the isntructions verbatim from the install and configuration tutorials. The last three lines of my bashrc are currently (before applying Lorenz's update):

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks
export ROS_WORKSPACE=~/ros_workspace
```

I also don't understand why roscreate-pkg works fine when I use it without NXT in mind.

EDIT 1.1: I ran all of Lorenz's suggested commands verbatim. After trying to run the command: `rosws set ~/ros_overlay/sandbox`

I get this:

```
     Add element: 
 {'other': {'local-name': '/home/noah/ros_overlay/sandbox'}}
Continue(y/n): y
Overwriting /home/noah/ros_workspace/.rosinstall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosws", line 66, in <module>
    sys.exit(rosinstall.rosws_cli.rosws_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall/rosws_cli.py", line 519, in rosws_main
    return ws_commands[command](workspace, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall/multiproject_cli.py", line 318, in cmd_set
    shutil.move(os.path.join(config.get_base_path(), self.config_filename), "%s.bak"%os.path.join(config.get_base_path(), self.config_filename))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 264, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 99, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/noah/ros_workspace/.rosinstall'
```

Notice the last line.

EDIT 1.2: All of the commands ran fine up to: `rosws set ~/ros_overlay/sandbox`

The output of the following command is below: `ls -l ~/ros_workspace`

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 noah noah 4096 2012-06-25 09:18 beginner_tutorials
```

I found the `.rosinstall` in the `~/ros_overlay` instead of `~/ros_workspace`

Is there a way to move it or modify the command?

Also, I haven't changed anything since I first entered the rosws set command, but now there is a new error output for it:

```
ERROR: Ambiguous workspace: ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/noah/ros_workspace, /home/noah/ros_overlay/.rosinstall
```

EDIT 1.3: I feel like the issue isn't with my workspaces or whatnot. I feel like it is with the actual [NXT Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_ros/Tutorials/Getting%20started#Create_a_Scratch_Package). The tutorial tells me to roscd to the NXT directory and then run the create package command. By me being in the NXT directory, /opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt, won't running roscreate-pkg attempt to create my package in the current directory instead of my workspace? In the [Creating Package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage#Creating_a_New_ROS_Package) tutorial, the user is told to roscd into their workspace before creating the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37226/permission-denied-/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/learning_nxt/) by [Nezteb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2691/nezteb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-25**:
That's interesting. The rosws init should actually create the .rosinstall file in ~/ros_workspace. Did you get any errors while executing rosws init? After executing it, what's the output of `ls -l ~/ros_workspace`?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-25**:
re EDIT 1: Your .bashrc had a workspace setup correctly (for electric). The reason for the error is that you tried to create a package in the installed nxt stack instead of your home workspace. This is always bad and independent of electric or fuerte.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-25**:
As I said at the end of my question, you should call roscreate in ~/ros_overlay/sandbox. Ignore what the NXT tutorial or any other tutorial says about where to create packages :) and always use your sandbox dir. The NXT tutorial probably assumes an installation from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should never try to edit, create or change files in /opt/ros/.... Instead, create a overlay in your home directory. To create an overlay for electric, just execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install -U rosinstall
rosws init ~/ros_overlay /opt/ros/electric
mkdir ~/ros_overlay/sandbox
source ~/ros_overlay/setup.bash
rosws set ~/ros_overlay/sandbox
```

Now open your ~/.bashrc and change the line

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

to

```
source ~/ros_overlay/setup.bash
```

Now close and re-open your terminal and execute the command `roscreate-pkg` in ~/ros_workspace/sandbox.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-25**:
Ah. Sorry. I screwed up the `source` line. Edited my question to fix it. Of course you should source the setup.bash in ros_overlay, not in ros_workspace.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-25**:
There was another mistake in the commands above. I forgot that you have to source setup.bash before calling rosws set, instead your ROS_WORKSPACE variable is not set correctly. Sorry for that.